# How to make an HTML character equal to its keyboard equivalent [ed: ascii code] in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, character

I'm trying to check if a variable exists in the LMS (BrainHoney) that our school is using. The variables are surrounded by dollar signs.  In order to see if the variable is in use I would like to try an if statement to the effect of alert("$Hello$" == "& #36;Hello& #36;");

If the variable wasn't in use, $Hello$ would remain $Hello$ instead of being replaced by a different string of text.

Unfortunately this returns false because they are not the same.  What should I change so that if the LMS leaves the text string as $Hello$ that I could check for it?

Comment: Um, does the title of this question have anything to do with the content?

Comment: In what context are you able to add javascript to the LMS?

Comment: With <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert("\044Hello\044" == "$Hello$");
```

Use the ascii value of $ in octal escaped by javascript.

Or:

```
alert("&#36;Hello&#36;" == "$Hello$");
```

This is the ascii value of $ in hex, escaped by the html.

Comment: The first example worked for me in octal, but not in ascii.
Thanks!

Comment: You mean hex, because they are both ascii.

Answer (score 0):

$ is not an html special character and the html will probably maintain the $ and not have the encoded representation so you probably need to use eval function for this (unless you want to pollute your global array with all these strings which is a bad idea).

assuming $Hello$ is instantiated somewhere like $Hello$ = 'Hi' and you are parsing through html and you come across a potential replacement and put it into a var called lookupStr, you could do the following.

```
if ( typeof( eval(lookupStr) ) != "undefined")
    replacement = lookupStr;
else
    eval(replacement = eval(lookupStr));
```

Then just replace the html portion with the replacement variable.

Comment: In the LMS, there is a variable set by the database depending on which course you are viewing ex. $COURSE_ID$, and anywhere the LMS encounters that string '$COURSE_ID$', it replaces it with the real course id.  There are other variables that don't always initialize, but I need a more clever way to check for them rather than what I have been trying. The LMS won't replace the $variable$ if it doesn't exist and leaves it as the string $variable$.
Is there a way to make a string containing $ == & #36?

Answer (score 0):

If you're reasonably sure the replacement won't start with a dollar sign, how about

```
"$Hello$".charAt(0) == "$"
```

?

Comment: This also worked. I'm glad you guys are much smarter than me!